# Can't compare char

Tags: java

```
  boolean isGender = gender == "M";
```

this statement returns an error "incomparable types"
the rest of the code before that is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BMR
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  //Scanner
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Get info
  System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
  String name = in.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Gender (M or F): ");
  String genderString = in.next();
  char gender = genderString.charAt(0);
  System.out.println("Enter your age: ");
  int age = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Height in inches: ");
  int height = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Weight in pounds: ");
  int weight = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println();

  //calculate BMR
  boolean isGender = gender == "M";
```

no idea why this doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

`"M"` is not a character, it's `String`

Based on your code, you should be using `gender == 'M'`

As a side note, if `gender` was a `String`, you should be using `gender.equals("M")` or if don't care about the case, you could use `gender.equalsIgnoreCase("M")` instead.

Comment: @user2526522 Subtle, I know ;)

Comment: Remember, double quotes are for `String`, single quotes for `char` ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
boolean isGender = gender == 'M';
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html